# How do I plot a point on a line of best fit?

Tags: windows-7, charts

I have a line of best fit graph on excel, and I want to plot points on it with 3 new data entries that only have Y axis values - and I'll get X axis values from the line of best fit. How can I do this?

Here's my graph now. I want to move the orange points over to the line of best fit.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLDWL.png

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming
>
> 1. that your chart is in a recent version of Excel, and
> 2. that the "best fit" line is actually an Excel trendline, derived from a data series of the associated points, and
> 3. that your chart is an XY/Scatter chart.
>
> If any of those assumptions aren't true, please update your question
> with the relevant additional info for a better solution.

The problem is simple to solve.

1. Format the trendline, and select Display Equation on Chart
2. Add a second series for your new values, using the Y(vertical) values you've provided and using the trendline equation to generate X(horizontal) values for the corresponding Y values.
3. Plot the new series on your chart.

[image]